# Best way to display full video background

Tags: jquery, html, css, performance

I am current working on fixing up a clients website who wants a background. I am currently trying `Bigvideo.js` with a local `.mp4` file. With `Bigvideo.js` i cannot get it to view on Firefox, only Chrome as well..

`ec2-23-21-228-183.compute-1.amazonaws.com/Marketcraftproductions.com/`

Its at times very laggy. What are some ways i can lower bandwidth and help fix my problem?
Should i implement a load screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have two problems:

1. You cannot view it on Firefox beacuse Firefox does not include non-free codecs apart from h264. You should encode your video in another format/container, like webm, h264 or ogv/Theora, just to name a few.
2. Yes, you should implement a load screen because videoclips can be huge. You can draw inspiration from [this web campaign](http://www.bethenightmeister.com/)

Note: I am in no way affiliated with the brand whose campaign I linked to. Simply, that's a very good example of what the OP needs.

### Some tips

To make the video background load faster, you could:

1. encode the video with different sizes, for small, medium, large screens and select what to load based on the screensize of the client.
2. reduce frame rate, at 10fps or less, *provided that there is no rapid motion*
3. avoid having a video as background... just sayin' :)

Comment: okay i will do this. In general, What about performance-wise? Will this be the best practice to use video?